# how to mount a ntfs volume for all users with rw permissions with ntfs-3g binary?

Tags: android, ntfs

I am using a cross compiled binary for android.
I used a command 
ntfs-3g /dev/block/mmcblk1 /storage/sdcard0/mysdcard
However when i exit the superuser and become a normal user. I am not able to view the device mounted on sdcard 3. I am only able to browse the filesystem as a root user. How do i mount the drive for all users publicly?

Answer (score 0):

my experience with ntfs-3g in linux is with Suse,
and I recently downloaded the source for ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23.
Going from memory I built it from source I think by simply

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23
make
make install
```

in any case if that is not correct there is either a *README* or *INSTALL* file explaining what to do.

After that I added `/opt/ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23` to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and also to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and uninstalled the system installed version of ntfs-3g so I know I was using the new version.

I could then successfully mount by hitachi 3tb hard disk I had formatted as ntfs from Windows 10 Home edition.

In linux in /etc/fstab my default mount line for mounting by device_id was this

```
/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDS723030ALA640_MK0311YHGWTYNA-part2 /data                ntfs-3g    users,gid=users,fmask=133,dmask=022,locale=en_US.UTF-8 0 0
```

this resulted in my disk mounting under a /data folder but because of **fmask** and **dmask** only root could get into the /data folder.

set **fmask=111** and **dmask=000** to make all files **-rw-rw-rw** and all directories **drwxrwxrwx**.

again, this was with the latest ntfs-3g_ntfsprogs-2017.3.23 that was available as of 2018-02-24.  I do not know if **dmask** and **fmask** are new features in ntfs-3g, i don't remember noticing them in earlier versions *where it just worked*.  I mention all this because in SLES 11.4 the native version of ntfs-3g from the SDK works and it mounts my win10 ntfs data drive no problem, but in SLES 12.3 whatever that native ntfs-3g from the SDK was did not work, gave error -1003 or -3003, thus the manual update to latest ntfs-3g and noticing the extra security preventing default read/write access to the mounted drive... requiring the modification of *fmask* and *dmask*